# copy odbc from win xp to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, odbc, datasource

I have ODBC Setting on Windows XP which i like to copy onto my new PC which has Windows 7.

On windows Xp the location of the ODBC is C:\Program Files\Common Files\ODBC but i can't find this location on windows 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this setting lives in the registry.

the 32 bit node

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

the 64 bit node

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

Don't forget there is a ODBC Data Sources node in these trees that acts as the *index*. ie

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources
```

Answer (score 0):

That location may, or may have, contained ODBC file DSN(s) (.dsn files containing ODBC DSN configurations)...

So - it should do no harm to reproduce this file system location and its contents.

Of course, if the location is empty then it would seem it is not being used and copying to the new machine will serve no purpose...